# How to run npm sh script on Windows and Unix

Tags: node.js, bash, batch-file, npm

I want to run a `sh` script that detects my `npm` version via `npm scripts`.
I have the following script and it works cool:

```
if [ $(npm -v | cut -c 1 | awk '{print $1\"<3\"}' | bc -l) != 0 ]; then echo '[ERROR] You need npm version @>=3\n' && false; fi
```

But this script works only on *NIX when I run the script on windows I got a error:

`$(npm was unexpected at this time.`

I want to detect if I'm running the script on Windows then don't execute the script, I tried this, but again only works on *NIX:

```
if [ 'uname -s' != CYGWIN* ]; then if [ $(npm -v | cut -c 1 | awk '{print $1\"<3\"}' | bc -l) != 0 ]; then echo '[ERROR] You need npm version @>=3\n' && false; fi; fi
```

Then I got:

`'uname was unexpected at this time.`

I was checking that the equivalent of `uname` on windows is [`systeminfo`](http://www.lemoda.net/windows/windows2unix/windows2unix.html)

But if I use `systeminfo` then I got the undefined on *NIX.

Any ideas of how can I make this script work on Windows && *NIX?

Comment: Bash and batch are completely different languages. To get that script to run in Windows, you either need to install Cygwin, be running Windows 10, or completely rewrite the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to execute your bash script on a platform that is not Windows you could check the platform with node itself (assuming that node is installed) using [`os.platform()`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_platform)

```
scripts: {      
  checkNpmVersion: "node -e \"process.exit(require('os').platform() === 'win32')\" && ./check-npm.sh"
}
```

Or even better you could write your little script in node so that it works on any platform (again assuming that node is installed)

```
// check-npm.js
const exec = require('child_process').exec

exec('npm -v', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  if (err) throw err
  if (stdout.match(/^3/)) throw "npm>3 required"
})
```

And in the scripts field

```
scripts: {      
  checkNpmVersion: "node check-npm.js"
}
```

Tested on Win7 with Node v4.4.5 and npm 2.15.5

Comment: Wow, thank you, I was complicating myself with bash and batch when I know node.